# Can you use a prepared statement in MySQL with "On Duplicate Key Update"?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I can't find any reference to using prepared statements with "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" with MySQL and PHP.  Am I correct in thinking that this is not possible?

-Jim

Answer (score 20):

Here is a generalized example of this usage:

```
$db->prepare('
INSERT INTO tableName (id, col1, col2, col3...)
VALUES (?,?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  col1 = VALUES(col1),
        col2 = VALUES(col2),
        col3 = VALUES(col3)
');

$stmt->bind_param('isss',
                  $id,
                  $col1,
                  $col2,
                  $col3
                 );
$db->execute($stmt);

if ($id == null) { //If you need the auto increment from the insert.
  $newId = $stmt->insert_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run every SQL query as a prepared statement. I don't know why you think there would be any exception for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Try it first and ask us if there are any problems.

Comment: Thanks Emil.  I will give it a try, although I can't picture how it would work.  Would you add the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to the query in mysqli_prepare and also have the replacement values as ? marks?  If that will work then it would be very useful to me. I will report on my results, although it may be a while before I have time to try this.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

You can most certainly use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with PHP+MySQL. Have you tried it? If you have, what problem did you run into?

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear, so I edited it.  I have used ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE many times, but never with a prepared statement.  I looked several places for instructions on how this might be done but found nothing.  Before I waste an afternoon on futile experimentation I thought I would check to see if anyone can confirm that this is actually feasible.

-Jim